# Deleting an application directory from iss with appcmd and reports identifer needed

Tags: iis, appcmd

I have somehow created an application directory with the `appcmd` command that  has hidden all of my applications directory.

I can do a list of my application directories with `appcmd` and I think the last directory I created has the file path with a double quote character at the end, so I'm trying to delete that one application directory.

When I run the command `appcmd list app` I get the list of my application directories which do not show up in the UI.

Here is a list of the last three:

- APP "Default Web Site/hotele/language90" (applicationPool:DefaultAppPool)
- APP "Default Web Site/hotele/business900" (applicationPool:DefaultAppPool)
- APP "Default Web Site/hotelk" (applicationPool:DefaultAppPool)

When I attempt to delete the hotelk one which is the one I think is messing up all of the directories I try running this command:

```
appcmd delete app "Default Web Site"/"hotelk"
```

It gives me this error:

> message:Must use exact identifier for APP object with verb DELETE.

I've tried many different combinations of this delete syntax and not use what is meant by the identifier?

I can't delete this application directory with the IIS UI since when I go there all of my application directories do not appear.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to delete the app from Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager GUI.

If you can't find your app there you can manually edit IIS configuration file (ApplicationHost.config):

- Go to path `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config`
- **Create a backup of ApplicationHost.config file**
- Open ApplicationHost.config file
- Search the name of the app you want to remove (ex. **hotelk**). You should find it in the `<sites>` section:

  ```xml
  <sites>
      <site name="Default Web Site" id="1">
          ...
      </site>
      <site name="hotelk&quot;" id="2">
          <application path="/">
              <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="d:\test" />
          </application>
          <bindings>
              <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />
          </bindings>
      </site>
      <siteDefaults>
          ...
      </siteDefaults>
      <applicationDefaults applicationPool="DefaultAppPool" />
      <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
  </sites>
  ```
- remove the entire  node containing the site you want to delete
- save the file

Answer (score 0):

If you want delete the app using appcmd this is the right command:

```
appcmd delete app "Default Web Site/hotelk"
```